# app.post without next (next should be undefined)

Tags: node.js, express, connect, mocha.js

In my routes.js I have:

```
app.post('/api/useraccounts', useraccountController.create);
```

In my useraccountController.js I have:

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
var registerUseraccountViewModel = new RegisterUseraccountViewModel(req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName,
                                                                    req.body.email, req.body.password);
//Validation of parameters done inside viewmodel
if(registerUseraccountViewModel instanceof Error) {
    res.json(406, { error: registerUseraccountViewModel.message });
    if(next) next();
} else {
    useraccountBusinessLogic.create(registerUseraccountViewModel, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            res.json(400, { error: err.message });
        } else {
            res.json(200, { useraccount: data });
        }
        //console.log(callback);
        if(next) next();
    });
}
```

}

I basically need my next not for handing over to the next route but for asynchronous unit testing with Mocha:

```
it('should return an error json because the useraccount already exists', function(done) {
//Insert useraccount to database so there will be a dupplicate
useraccountController.create(helper.requestMock, helper.responseMock, function() {
    useraccountController.create(helper.requestMock, helper.responseMock, function() {
        assert(helper.responseStatusCode == 400);
        assert(helper.responseJson['error'] && helper.responseJson['error'] != "");
        done();
    });
});
```

})

The tests are working great.
Unfortunately next is not undefined when the method is called from my routes.js. But I'd like it to be undefined when called by app.post in routes.js.

Answer (score 0):

That does the trick:

```
app.post('/api/useraccounts', function(req, res) {
    useraccountController.create(req, res);
});
```